# How tall are Aragorn and Elendil?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-silmarillion

On both Tolkien Gateway and the Lord of the Rings wikia it says that Elendil is 7’11 (241cm) and Aragon is 6’6 (198cm). I have read the *Lord of the Rings* and the *Silmarillion* and neither of them mention the height of these two characters, except that they were tall.

Where do these values come from? Are they canonical?

Comment: There is a superscript [1] beside their respective heights in the websites. The respective citations (and *page numbers*) are both correct.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Elendil's height comes from the Unfinished Tales.

In the *Unfinished Tales*, we are given one of the only measurements of the height of a person in all the works, that being of Elendil. Elendil is described as being:

> more than man-high by nearly half a ranga
> <sub>Unfinished Tales: Appendix, Númenórean Linear Measures</sub>

'Man-high' in this context is a measurement based on a typical Númenórean's height, defined as two rangar or seventy-six inches. Adding a further half a ranga gives ninety-five inches, so Elendil's height was no more than seven feet, eleven inches (or 2.41 metres). This is however an upper bound as he was only taller than "man-high" by "nearly" half a ranga.

> The Númenórean ranga was slightly longer than our yard,approximately thirty-eight inches, owing to their greater stature.
>
> ...
>
> Thus two rangar was often called ‘man-high’, whichat thirty-eight inches gives an average height of six feet four inches;
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

## Aragorn's height comes from "LotR: A Reader's Companion"

The source for the height of Aragorn on Tolkien Gateway comes from the *Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion* edited by Hammond and Scull, which sources some of Tolkien's notes from the Bodleian Library.

> Aragorn, direct descendant of Elendil and his son Isildur, both of whom had been seven feet tall, must nonetheless have been a very tall man ..., probably at least 6 ft. 6; and Boromir, of high Numenorean lineage, not much shorter (say 6 ft. 4). [Tolkien Papers, Bodleian Library, Oxford]
> <sub>Hammond & Scull (eds) - Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion: Page 229</sub>

Comment: Weirdly this rather changes how I see the "men" of the Fellowship. Especially, in the mountain pass chapter.

Comment: Unintentional hilarity: in Australia a "ranga" is slang for anyone with ginger hair. (height indeterminate)

Comment: @AdamEberbach The slang term was spread abroad by the works of the great Chris Lilley